# Question with get_the_term_list

Tags: terms

I'm using this function right now in my theme to show each project's custom taxonomy. In this case, the custom taxonomy is `tipo_de_tarea`:

```
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'tipo_de_tarea' );
```

I have various tipo_de_tareas. I would like the function to display a shorter name, instead of the complete name of each taxonomy, for example:

- Apuntes => AP
- Ejercicios => EJ

As I show in this example, the left side has the current design, and the right has the wished:

[image]

I guess that I need to add `if` conditions for each tipo de tarea and the wished name, but how can I do this? I don't know the code for this.

Also, I would like each one to have a different class that can be assigned a different background color for each one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `get_terms()` and loop through it - using the term description as the "short name" and slug as the specific class ( or you could use an array of colors of your choice ). Let's look at a quick example:

```
<?php
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'category' );

    if( ! empty( $terms ) ) : ?>

        <?php foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

            <div class="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->description; ?></div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php
    endif;
?>
```

If you wanted to make a list out of it or [link from it](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) you have full control over the HTML - let me know if you have questions about the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I found finally help in another place and I'm now using these functions in functions.php:

```
    // A callback function to add a custom field to our "presenters" taxonomy  
function presenters_taxonomy_custom_fields($tag) {  
   // Check for existing taxonomy meta for the term you're editing  
    $t_id = $tag->term_id; // Get the ID of the term you're editing  
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id" ); // Do the check  
?>  

<tr class="form-field">  
    <th scope="row" valign="top">  
        <label for="abreviatura"><?php _e('Abreviatura'); ?></label>  
    </th>  
    <td>  
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[abreviatura]" id="term_meta[abreviatura]" size="25" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['abreviatura'] ? $term_meta['abreviatura'] : ''; ?>"><br />  
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Abreviatura del tipo de tarea'); ?></span>  
    </td>  
</tr>  

<?php  
}  

// A callback function to save our extra taxonomy field(s)  
function save_taxonomy_custom_fields( $term_id ) {  
    if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {  
        $t_id = $term_id;  
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id" );  
        $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );  
            foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ){  
            if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ){  
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];  
            }  
        }  
        //save the option array  
        update_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id", $term_meta );  
    }  
}  

// Add the fields to the "presenters" taxonomy, using our callback function  
add_action( 'tipo_de_tarea_edit_form_fields', 'presenters_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );  

// Save the changes made on the "presenters" taxonomy, using our callback function  
add_action( 'edited_tipo_de_tarea', 'save_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

And I call the code with:

```
    <?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'tipo_de_tarea' );
if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)): 
    foreach($terms as $term): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->slug, 'tipo_de_tarea'); ?>" rel="tag" class="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" title="<?php echo $term->name; ?>"><?php echo $term->abreviatura; ?></a>
    <?php
    endforeach;
endif; 
?>
```

But there is some problem with the functions and I only see a blank column...

Anyone knows where is the problem?

Thanks!